# MySQL grant syntax and wildcards

Tags: mysql

To allow `someuser` to do SELECTs on `mydb`, I can execute the following statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Suppose that I want allow SELECTs on only two tables: `event` and `event_detail`.

I guess I can do the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.event TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.event_detail TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Would the following also work? (Supposing no other tables are matched)

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.event* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Comment: My suspicion is it won't work (or if, then with the `%` wildcard). But why not try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - wildcards can only be used for entire table or database names.

You'll have to either type the grant statement for every table explicitly, or write a script or program to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `GRANT` syntax:

```
GRANT
... priv_level ...

priv_level:
    *
  | *.*
  | db_name.*
  | db_name.tbl_name
  | tbl_name
  | db_name.routine_name
```

So I guess you can't. You can, anyway, use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to find those tables with the name prefix you desire, and then iterate through them.